# Unable to bind expressions with input values

Tags: javascript, angularjs, html

I was learning [AngularJS](http://www.w3schools.com/angular/angular_intro.asp). To practically fiddle with it, I was trying to create a basic calculator which read values from input box, does basic calculation and give output.

[Here](http://jsfiddle.net/xameeramir/tub4z76b/) it is:

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<div data-ng-app=''>
    
    <p>Enter first number: <input type="number" ng-model="input1"></p>
        <p>The number you entered is <mark ng-bind="input1"></mark></p>
    <p>Enter second number: <input type="number" ng-model="input2"></p>
        <p>The number you entered is <mark ng-bind="input2"></mark></p>

        <p>
            Subtraction: {{ (Property.input1|number) + (Property.input2|number) }}
        </p>

        <p>
            Sum: {{ (Property.input1|number) + (Property.input2|number) }}
        </p>
    
        <p>
            Product: {{ (Property.input1|number) * (Property.input2|number) }}
        </p>
        
        <p>
            Division: {{ (Property.input1|number) / (Property.input2|number) }}
        </p>
        
</div>
```

The values doesn't seem to be automatically getting calculated. Can someone guide?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You misused the angular ng-model variables evaluation.

For example for the Sum you just need to write

> {{ input1 + input2 }}

This is the new working code:

```
<div data-ng-app=''>

    <p>Enter first number: <input type="number" ng-model="input1"></p>
        <p>The number you entered is <mark ng-bind="input1"></mark></p>
    <p>Enter second number: <input type="number" ng-model="input2"></p>
        <p>The number you entered is <mark ng-bind="input2"></mark></p>

        <p>
            Subtraction: {{ input1 - input2 }}
        </p>

        <p>
            Sum: {{ input1 + input2 }}
        </p>

        <p>
            Product: {{ input1 * input2 }}
        </p>

        <p>
            Division: {{ input1 / input2 }}
        </p>

</div>
```

Comment: Thanks @fbid - now it's working perfect. Btw, what does `(Property.input1|number)` mean? I saw that syntax somewhere but don't know the use.

Comment: The " | number " is an angular filter used to format the value. You can find more info here: https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/filter/number

Comment: As for the Property.input1, you are referring to a input1 property on a Property Object. 
In order to use that notation you have to assign `ng-model="Property.input1" `instead of `ng-model="input1"` and then something like:  `{{ (Property.input1 / Property.input2) | number:2 }}`